# With the ImportExcel module, is there a way to create a pivot table in excel that's in tabular format (and without subtotals)?

Tags: excel, powershell

I can't find any command or property that would address this. I also tried checking dfinke's github, couldn't find anything.

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

I looked here for some ideas but nothing. I am mostly interested in creating pivot tables in tabular format, but if it's also possible to have headers repeat and remove subtotals, that would be ideal. My pivot tables currently just export in outline format.